# How to merge / concat two pandas dataframes with different length?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, merge

I would like to concat/merge two pandas dataframes but I don't get the right result. I have following dataframes:

```
df1

    Username      | User_trim
-------------------------------
0   Maria M       | Maria
1   FakeName      | N/A
2   Achim B       | Achim
3   FlashMaster11 | N/A
4   Fakename2     | N/A
5   Gustav W      | Gustav


df2
    0        |1       | 2
---------------------------------
0   Maria M  | Maria  | female
2   Achim B  | Achim  | male
5   Gustav W | Gustav | male
```

I would like to have following result dataframe:

```
    Username      | User_trim | Gender
---------------------------------
0   Maria M       | Maria     | female
1   FakeName      | N/A       | N/A
2   Achim B       | Achim     | male
3   FlashMaster11 | N/A       | N/A
4   Fakename2     | N/A       | N/A
5   Gustav W      | Gustav    | male
```

I tried following code

```
result = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1,ignore_index=True)
```

But I get a wrong result but the right length of the table. So I tried this:

```
df1.merge(df2,how='outer', left_on='Username', right_on=0)
```

This code seems like I get the right result but the table is bigger then df1 (I mean by rows)?

I dont have a problem, when I merge the dataframe and get get all columns. I can drop them. Its just the problem to merge them with different length and to get them in the right row.

Does anyone can give me an advice how I can get the result table?

Answer (score 1):

I think need `left join` in [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
df = df1.merge(df2,how='left', left_on='Username', right_on=0)
print (df)
        Username User_trim         0       1       2
0        Maria M     Maria   Maria M   Maria  female
1       FakeName       NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN
2        Achim B     Achim   Achim B   Achim    male
3  FlashMaster11       NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN
4      Fakename2       NaN       NaN     NaN     NaN
5       Gustav W    Gustav  Gustav W  Gustav    male
```

Solution if need append new column(s) by `merge` without remove unnecessary columns is first `rename` at least one column use for join (here `Username` in both `DataFrame`s) and then select all necessary columns (always join column + all another new columns):

```
df22 = df2.rename(columns={0:'Username', 2:'Gender'})[['Username', 'Gender']]
print (df22)
   Username  Gender
0   Maria M  female
1   Achim B    male
2  Gustav W    male

df = df1.merge(df22,how='left', on='Username')
print (df)
        Username User_trim  Gender
0        Maria M     Maria  female
1       FakeName       NaN     NaN
2        Achim B     Achim    male
3  FlashMaster11       NaN     NaN
4      Fakename2       NaN     NaN
5       Gustav W    Gustav    male
```

---

If need add only one new column use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df1['Gender'] = df1['Username'].map(df2.set_index(0)[2])
print (df1)
        Username User_trim  Gender
0        Maria M     Maria  female
1       FakeName       NaN     NaN
2        Achim B     Achim    male
3  FlashMaster11       NaN     NaN
4      Fakename2       NaN     NaN
5       Gustav W    Gustav    male
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your indices are already aligned, you can align column names and then use [`pd.DataFrame.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df2 = df2.rename(columns={0: 'Username', 1: 'User_trim', 2: 'Gender'})

res = df1.combine_first(df2)

print(res)

#    Gender User_trim       Username
# 0  female     Maria        Maria M
# 1     NaN       N/A       FakeName
# 2    male     Achim        Achim B
# 3     NaN       N/A  FlashMaster11
# 4     NaN       N/A      Fakename2
# 5    male    Gustav       Gustav W
```